# Easy lib to zip a folder and sub-folders/files in nodejs without recursing yourself?

Tags: node.js, zip

Is there any easy lib that can zip an entire folder's contents in a simple line, without having to recurse through the folder structure yourself, along the lines of:

```
zip('./folder/').output('zipped.js')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [zip-folder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-folder) like this:

**Installation**:

```sh
npm i zip-folder
```

**Usage**:

```js
var zipFolder = require('zip-folder');
 
zipFolder('/path/to/the/folder', '/path/to/archive.zip', function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('oh no!', err);
    } else {
        console.log('EXCELLENT');
    }
});
```